# Ширина блока на оставшуюся ширину страницы

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка, css

Вопрос болезненный для меня. Вот есть контейнер, на всю ширину страницы, есть блоки внутри: от одного до нескольких — с шириной, меняющейся в зависимости от контента, а последний — должен заполнять оставшееся пространство. Как задать его ширину в CSS (JS не предлагать, сам знаю, как). Есть способ, вообще?

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="part">Some string</div>
    <div class="part">One more string</div>
    <div class="part">100</div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, например?

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.part,
.fill {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.fill {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="part">Some string</div>
  <div class="part">One more string</div>
  <div class="part">100</div>
  <div class="fill">1</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Vertigo/t4dx5a52/

Comment: Кхм, прошу прощения. Вопрос был глупый. Спасибо за напоминание.

Comment: Все в порядке. А еще посмотрите flexbox-методы. Приятной работы.